# how to extract the physical file from the application's private storage in android

Tags: android, internal-storage

I've stored my XML file in application's private storage,

this is the path which was returned.

/data/data/MyPackageName/files

now how do i extract the physical file from there.

Comment: from device? or emulator?

Answer (score 0):

To read data from private/internal storage you need your app files folder and read content from here

```
File yourFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "hello.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + files;
File myDir = new File(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

/data/data/MyPackageName has restrictive permissions, so you do it in two steps: First copy the file to /sdcard, then read it from /sdcard with `adb pull`. If you have root, `adb shell` followed by `su` and `cp /data/data/MyPackageName/files/yourfile.xml /sdcard` will copy to /sdcard. Then on the host you retrieve the file with `adb pull /sdcard/yourfile.xml`. If you don't have root, you must write java code to copy.